# I want to input address (0) in function argument in Remix.org

Tags: solidity

```
function vote(uint index, uint select, address _voter) public onlyActiveProposal(index) returns(bool)
```

I want to input `address(0)` in function argument

Like this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` (`0x` and then 40 zeros).